# String index from line index and column index in NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

Is there any easy way to get the string index in an NSString if I have the line number and column number?

For example:

`myString` =

```
abc
def
ghi
```

`[myString getIndexFromLineNumber:2 columnNumber:1]` should return the index of `h` in myString, so in this example it should be `10` (assuming new lines are 1 char long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way to do this, so you're going to have to write a category for NSString.
Take a look at [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it will help you quite a bit.

**Tips:**

- Wrap the code in the method in a `while (![scanner isAtEnd])` to keep scanning through the string in a loop.
- Use `[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] intoString:NULL]` and `[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:NULL]` to skip a line (keep doing this until you've reached the line you want, then read the current line and return a given character).